# How to display data after clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, checkbox

I am new to ReactJS, I have "providers" data from an API displayed in checkboxes. I want to click on a provider then display products that particular provider has.

Currently I can get data from the API for both the Provider and Products, but when I return the data for the products it brings back everything in the API array however I want products of specific provider.

**this is the API:**

My code currently for retrieving products data currently looks like this:

[image: CODE]

NB: this returns all products in the array but I want to check on "Evotel Provider" and get Evotel Products.

Please help

[image: Screenshot of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your code as text in your question rather than posting an image of your code. See [markdown formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
    {providers.map(item => <>
        <div>
             // this will be the checkbox div   
        </div>
        {item.provider ? listItems.products
                                   .filter(product => product.provider === item.provider)
                                   .map(p => <div>// show list here</div>)
        : null
        }
    </>
    }
```

Although I think the problem is that you are using item.provider as value for the checkbox. Where as the value should be a boolean.

You can convert value from other datatype to boolean by !!(double bang operator)

`... value={!!item.provider} ...`

Also check out the docs for javascript [array.includes() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

Comment: This is not working, thank you. I will go through the doc you have shared.

Comment: The main problem is that item.provider is not boolean.